# Why does a list appear as a comment with Python Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the addresses of Dunkin' locations using this website: https://www.dunkindonuts.com/en/locations?location=10001. However, when trying to access the list of each Dunkin' on the web page, it shows up as comment. How do I access the list? I've never done web scraping before.

Here's my current code, I'm expecting a list of Dunkin' stores which I can then extract the addresses from.[image]

Comment: Please write your code as editable code. Use ```Your Code``` to write it. :)

Comment: You're getting a comment because that's what's in the HTML. Use `View Source` in the browser and you'll see the same thing.

Comment: The actual store list is added using JavaScript. `requests.get()` doesn't run the JS, it just returns the raw HTML.

Comment: Try getting the `text` of `storeList`

Answer (score 0):

`requests.get()` will return the raw HTML for a web page. This is only the beginning of the journey when you view this page in the browser. Your browser will parse that HTML to create the DOM. It will load other resources, such as images and scripts from other files. Then it will execute those scripts. In the modern web, those scripts will modify the DOM to give the page that you finally see in the browser. `requests` alone doesn't give you all that.

One solution is to use a library that loads the HTML into a browser and does all of the magic. `selenium` is one such library.